# Extract data between (' and '), using vba code

Tags: excel, vba

I want to Extract data between ('  and  '), using `vba` code.
e.g from `string =" ('128003848885492'), ('128003848885502')"`.I need `128003848885492` and  `128003848885502` and need to compare these values in other file separately.

please suggest.

thanks in advance.

Comment: so split on the `'` and use position 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

Remove unnecessary characters leaving the commas to split the string.  This will leave you a string array of numbers.

```
Sub Example()

    Dim StringValues  As String
    Dim ArrayValues() As String
    Dim Value As Variant

    StringValues = "('128003848885492'),('128003848885502')"

    'Remove unnecessary characters leaving the commas to split the string
    StringValues = Replace(StringValues, ")", "")
    StringValues = Replace(StringValues, "(", "")
    StringValues = Replace(StringValues, "'", "")

    ArrayValues = Split(StringValues, ",")

    For Each Value In ArrayValues

         Debug.Print CDbl(Value)

    Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Just `ArrayValues = Split(StringValues, "'")` and `For i = 1 to ubound(ArrayValues) Step 2` then `Debug.Print cdbl(ArrayValues(i))` no need to do any replacing.

Comment: Personally I'd would create a declare second array as long or double and add the numbers to it.  The reason  replacement is to simplify the comparison.  He is going to be doing comparisons on multiple files using multiple arrays.  The simpler the array the easier the comparisons.

Comment: There are an added benefits of doing it my way.  The OP could use worksheet functions on my array with confidence as well as copying the array into a range using range.resize.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, more generically and separating only numbers:

```
Dim str, newstr As String
Dim arr() As String
Dim i As Integer
str = "('128003848885492'), ('128003848885502')"
For i = 0 To Len(str) - 1
   If IsNumeric(Mid(str, i + 1, 1)) Or Mid(str, i + 1, 1) = "," Then
      newstr = newstr & Mid(str, i + 1, 1) 'We extract only the numbers and the comma.
   End If
Next i
arr = Split(newstr, ",")
MsgBox (arr(0)) 'first number
MsgBox (arr(1)) 'second number
```